# Zxing reader not working

Tags: iphone, qr-code, zxing

![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Im working QRCode scan images.I read some doc and finally added `zxingwidget.xcodeproj` library  under Dependencies. But when i was running i got some file missing error under `coresrc/zxing/BarcodeFormat.cpp`.So many files indicate red color.But,i have all those files inside folder. I don't why?

Comment: Share your error screenshot here.

Comment: why red color file indicating? I have these files in path.

Comment: Your all class header file are missing. That means you did not setup/copied library classes in your workspace/working project directory. Also set up proper source files/library path in XCode build setting.

Comment: @user2474320 Post screenshot of your project hirarchy and your "Header Search Paths" under your application and target settings.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this from one of my current projects hence I have cropped some of the portions.

Keep your Project Hierarchy as show in below image:

[image]

Under your Xcode, put Header Search Paths as:

**Project Settings:**

`../<Sub Project Name>/ZXingWidget/Classes` Keep this as "recursive"

`../../cpp/core/src` Keep this as "non-recursive"

**Target Settings:**

`../<Sub Project Name>/ZXingWidget/Classes` Keep this as "recursive"

`../cpp/core/src` Keep this as "non-recursive"

This should do it.

### Edit 1

1. Keep the "cpp" folder under "Iphone" folder. Just at the same level as "ScanTest" Folder
2. Change Header Search Paths as below in Project and Target Settings both:

- "../ScanTest/ZXingWidget/Classes". Keep it as "recursive".
- "../cpp/core/src" and keep it as "non-recursive"

Comment: I didn't get.what can i do now?

Comment: @user2474320 1) Change your Header Search Paths in your Project and Target Settings under Xcode. 2) Change your project structure as per mentioned in the Screenshot in my answer.

Comment: @user2474320: You need to replace "../ScanTest/ZXingWidget/Classes". Keep it as "recursive". Also need to use "../cpp/core/src" and keep it as "non-recursive" in addition to **EDIT-1** section in the above answer.

Comment: Im getting ZXingWidgetcontroller.h file not found.